# How can I retrieve Combobox's GWLP_USERDATA from WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX?

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, user-data

Most messages I've been using so far pass the HWND in the lParam. So I was using that value to retrieve the associated hwnd's object with `GWLP_USERDATA`, so I could do something like this:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        auto sender = (HWND)lParam;
        auto obj = getObj(sender);
        obj->myMethod();
    }
```

And get the method associated to the hwnd called. However, `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` for Combobox doesn't send the Combobox's `HWND` in the `lParam`. I have to send a `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` message but that requires the control's hwnd, that in that design, isn't available. So my question is: How can I retrieve the object associated to the combobox from `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX`? I couldn't think any other way to loop over all objects created so far(So I needed to keep an array of them), somehow filter that objects that are associated with a combobox control type, then use that hwnd in the `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` message. This seems kinda of bruta force. Are there a better approach than this? here's how I'm doing that currently:

```
    case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
    {
      auto dc = (HDC) wParam;
      SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
      COMBOBOXINFO info;
      
      for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(instances); i++)
      {
        auto obj = instances[i];
        if(obj->type != ControlType_combobox) 
            continue;
        memset(&info, 0, sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO));
        info.cbSize  = sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO);
        auto hCombo = instances[i];
        SendMessage(obj->hwnd, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, (LPARAM) &info);
        if((HWND)lParam == info.hwndList)
        {
            return (LRESULT) obj->hBrush;
        }
      }
    }
    break;
}
```

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comdlg32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define COUNTOF(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

enum ControlType
{
    ControlType_none,
    ControlType_button,
    ControlType_combobox
};

class Foo
{
public:

    int n = 0;
    const wchar_t *str = nullptr;
    HBRUSH hBrush = nullptr;
    ControlType type = ControlType_none;
    HWND hwnd = nullptr;

    void sayHello()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, str, L"", MB_OK);
    }

    Foo() { }

    ~Foo()
     {
        if(hBrush) {
            DeleteObject(hBrush);
            hBrush = nullptr;
        }
     }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HFONT getDefaultFont();
void SetDefaultFont(HWND hwnd);
void saveInstance(Foo *f);
void freeInstances();
void associateObj(HWND hwnd, Foo *instance);
Foo* getObj(HWND hwnd);

Foo *instances[12];
int instance_size = 0;

HFONT hDefaultSystemFont;

HINSTANCE g_hinst;

const wchar_t *items[] =
{ 
  L"Windows", L"Mac", 
  L"FreeBSD", L"Arch",
};

enum
{
  ID_COMBO = 10,
  ID_BTN1,
};


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    HWND hwnd;
    MSG  msg ;    
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Application";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);

    g_hinst = hInstance;
  
    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  100, 100, 300, 170, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg)
    {
    
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND hwndCombo = CreateWindow(L"Combobox", NULL, 
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWN,
                    10, 10, 120, 110, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_COMBO, g_hinst, NULL);
              auto f = new Foo;
              f->n = 10;
              f->str = L"Hello from combo!";
              f->hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 128, 0));
              f->type = ControlType_combobox;
              associateObj(hwndCombo, f);
              for (int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(items); i++)
              {
                SendMessageW(hwndCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) items[i]);
              }
              SetDefaultFont(hwndCombo);

              HWND btn1 =
              CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Click me!", 
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    5, 40, 90, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BTN1, g_hinst, NULL);
              auto f2 = new Foo;
              f2->n = 20;
              f2->str = L"Hello from button!";
              f2->type = ControlType_button;
              associateObj(btn1, f2);
              SetDefaultFont(btn1);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            DeleteObject(hDefaultSystemFont);
            hDefaultSystemFont = NULL;
            freeInstances();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            auto sender = (HWND)lParam;
            auto o = getObj(sender);
            o->sayHello();
        }
        break;

        case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
        {
          auto dc = (HDC) wParam;
          SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
          COMBOBOXINFO info;
          
          for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(instances); i++)
          {
            auto obj = instances[i];
            if(obj->type != ControlType_combobox) 
                continue;
            memset(&info, 0, sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO));
            info.cbSize  = sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO);
            auto hCombo = instances[i];
            SendMessage(obj->hwnd, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, (LPARAM) &info);
            if((HWND)lParam == info.hwndList)
            {
                return (LRESULT) obj->hBrush;
            }
          }
        }
        break;
    }
  
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void associateObj(HWND hwnd, Foo *instance)
{
    instance->hwnd = hwnd;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)(void*)instance);
    saveInstance(instance);
}

Foo* getObj(HWND hwnd)
{
    return (Foo*)(void*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
}

void saveInstance(Foo *f)
{
    instances[instance_size++] = f;
}

void freeInstances()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(instances); i++) {
        delete instances[i];
        instances[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

HFONT getDefaultFont()
{
  if(hDefaultSystemFont == NULL) {
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
    hDefaultSystemFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
  }
  return hDefaultSystemFont;
}


void SetDefaultFont(HWND hwnd)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM) getDefaultFont(), TRUE);
}
```

Comment: You can call `GetParent()` on the listbox `HWND` to get the combo's `HWND`.

Comment: Not a solution to your immediate issue, but consider using `SetProp`/`GetProp`. Since you are writing an abstraction over Windows' common controls, you are now fighting with not just one but two parties over who owns `GWLP_USERDATA`: Third-party applications and clients of your library.

Comment: @JonathanPotter like this? `auto sender = GetParent((HWND)lParam);` but ´getObj(sender)` is returning `NULL`

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your advice, I'll consider switch to `SetProp` / `GetProp`, sounds more appropriated.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a ComboBox, use `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` to get its ListBox's `HWND`, and then use `SetProp()` to save your object pointer in it. That way, in your `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` handler, you can use `GetProp()` on the provided `HWND` to access your object. No hunting needed.

**UPDATE**: as stated in a comment, you can also use `GetParent()` on the `HWND` provided by `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` to get its owning ComboBox's `HWND`, from which you can then access your associated object pointer using `getObj()`.

Comment: I did  keep the line `associateObj(hwndCombo, f); ` then `auto sender = GetParent((HWND)lParam);
          assert(sender != NULL);
          auto obj = getObj(sender);` but I'm getting `NULL` on `obj`. What am I missing?